# Url rewrite mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I've read about mod_rewrite:

And this should work, right?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^genre/([^/]*)$ /?genre=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to go from:

> www.site.com/?genre=test

to:

> www.site.com/genre/test

I have enabled: mod_rewrite.

Any idea, where I'm doing it wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
> RewriteRule ^/genre/([a-z]+)$ /index.php/?genre=$1    [L]
```

Comment: In the browser do you want `/genre/test` or `/?genre=test`? Please tell us what eactly is not working for you? Are you getting 404?

Comment: @anubhava I want `/genre/test` It's just not working, no errors. I'm using wordpress.

Comment: You rule looks fine to me, when you get a chance can you paste your access.log relevant snippet pls. Most likely Wordpress's existing rules are clashing with this rule.

Comment: @anubhava "GET /genre/action/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2401 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"

Comment: Interesting, it shows HTTP code 200 for URI `/genre/action/`, which means your rule is working fine and you are not getting 404. As per your rule it would be forwarding it to `/?genre=action` URI. Can you try adding some debug statements in your script/code service URI `/` which could be something like `index.html`, `index.php` etc.

Comment: @anubhava Added in the first post, I'm doing it correct? Still not working :/ Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Muazam, I corrected your edited rule in my answer below, please try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^genre/(.*)$ /index.php?genre=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Do you think something else can cause this? Thanks for the input and help.

Comment: I just tried it on my other virtualhost and it worked. Something wrong with the virtualhost. Any idea?

Comment: You're most welcome, I'm glad that you made it work eventually.